# SAP JCo missing libraries

Tags: java, jco

I'm trying to connect SAP system from Java with SAP JCo and I cannot find the libraries of `librfc32.dll`, `com.sap.utils` and `com.sap.mw`.

Am I doing something wrong? My JCo version is 3.0.17.

Answer (score 6):

The JCo API has been reworked and was redesigned with JCo release 3.0. Its classes were also relocated from packages com.sap.mw.jco.* to com.sap.conn.jco.*

Packages com.sap.mw.jco.* belong to the old JCo2 API, i.e. they were part of JCo 2.1. And I do not know package com.sap.utils. If you mean com.sap.mw.jco.util or com.sap.conn.jco.util they were/are internal packages of JCo and are not part of its public API, so these classes should not be used directly in your Java programs (just the same as with the sun.io.* packages).

Finally, librfc32.dll was only used by the old JCo 2.x versions. With JCo 3.0 all you need at runtime are the files sapjco3.jar and sapjco3.dll (on Windows).

And to make the picture complete:
JCo 2.1 went out of maintenance and support by SAP in 2013. So I would not deal with the old JCo2 API anymore unless you have to. And if you have to, it should be only for migrating old programs from using the deprecated JCo2 API to the new JCo3 API. Running SAP scenarios without having the right to get SAP support is not advisable, I think.